# Post data from the target URL to the target URL with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently trying to use cURL to log into a website to get some information I need. The website I'm trying to log in is using a duplicate submission token though.

Basically, every time you open the log in page a unique hash is generated, stored as a value in a hidden input field with the name "hash". This hash has to be sent along with the log in data.

This is what I have so far, it's working, but without the generated hash a log in is not possible.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$hash = "123";

$postData = array(
    'hash' => $hash,
    'login' => 'Login',
    'login_email' => 'email',
    'login_password' => 'pw',
    'redirect_to' => 'http://somewhere.com',
    'remember_me' => 0
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://somewhere.com/login',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

How can I grab the generated hash from the website and pass it to the POST data?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible with just PHP.  You'd have to send a request to the page and parse the input to get the hash value, then send a second request with the value, but at that point, a new value would be created since you're sending a new request.

Comment: they are trying to stop you doing this automatically, how about respecting that?

Answer (score 1):

VOILÀ ;)

It does a first connection to get the hash value and then POST it to te login page with a second connection.

I wrote it in 2 minutes but it should work well.

```
// retrieve web page to get hash value
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://somewhere.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // if there's https in the url this bypass the verification of the SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // if there's https in the url this bypass the verification of the SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.4.154.18 Safari/525.19");
ob_start();
curl_exec($ch);
$response = ob_get_clean();
curl_close($ch);

// extrapolate hash value from web page
preg_match_all('/input type="hidden" name="hash" value="(.*?)"/', $response, $matches);

// START LOGIN FLOW

$fields = array(
    'hash' => $matches[1][0],
    'login' => 'Login',
    'login_email' => 'email',
    'login_password' => 'pw',
    'redirect_to' => 'http://somewhere.com',
    'remember_me' => 0
);

// url-ify data for POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value){ $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

// open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://somewhere.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // if there's https in the url this bypass the verification of the SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // if there's https in the url this bypass the verification of the SSL certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: ".strlen($fields_string), "charset=ISO-8859-1"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.4.154.18 Safari/525.19");
ob_start();
curl_exec($ch);
$response = ob_get_clean();
curl_close($ch);

echo $response; // LOGGED IN ;)
```